# What is the analog of a vector bundle connection for a projective bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space, fiber-bundles

For a vector bundle, a connection is defined as a linear operator $\nabla:\Gamma(E)\rightarrow \Gamma(E\otimes T^*M)$, and the horizontal subspace is locally spanned by solutions of the equation $\nabla s_i=0$.  Is there a similar way of viewing connections on projective bundles?  If a projective bundle descends from a vector bundle, what is the relation between the connections?  Is there a good source to learn this information from (there are many good sources for vector bundles and principal bundles, but I have not seen any good sources on projective bundles).

Comment: Upon further research, I am going to look at the books Fibre Bundles by Husemoller and Differential Geometry: Cartan's Generalization of Klein's Erlangen Program by Sharpe, these look promising (as referenced in the wikipedia article on associated bundles, which gives some partial understanding)

Comment: Sharpe's book is hard going. What you want is a projective connection. Assuming you have some familiarity with the usual moving frames game in differential geometry, you might want to look at some discussion in section IV of Chern and Griffiths's *Abel's Theorem and Webs* (p. 89), Jber. d. Dt. Math. Verein 80 (1978).

Comment: Great, thanks for the references!

Answer (score 2):

You can define a connection on any surjective submersion $f:Y\rightarrow X$ as a splitting of the exact sequence of vector bundles over $Y$

$0\rightarrow VY\rightarrow TY\xrightarrow{Tf} f^*TX\rightarrow 0$,

where the vertical subspace $VY$ is defined to be $VY:=\ker(Tf)$. However, the definition is really only useful when $Y$ has the structure of a fibre bundle.

When $Y$ is a vector bundle it is possible to identify $VY\cong f^*E$ and in this case the usual idea of a connection on a vector bundle follows. In particular, the definition of a connection you give as an associated covariant derivative. Likewise when $Y$ is a principal $G$-bundle it is possible to identify $VY\cong f^*ad(Y)$, and the usual idea of a connection on a principal bundle follows.

A connection on a projective bundle $f:Y\rightarrow X$ is therefore a splitting of the above exact sequence. I'm not sure if there is a nice identification of the vertical subspace in this case. Neither am I sure whether defining it as a covariant derivative is particularly fruitful in this case.

If $Y$ is the projective bundle associated to a vector bundle $E\rightarrow M$ then it is easy to see that any vector bundle connection $\nabla$ on $E$ induces a connection on $E_0=E-M$ and this will descend to one on $Y$ if and only if it is equivariant with respect to the action of scalar multiplication on $E$.

It may be useful to view a rank $n$ vector bundle $E$ as the associated bundle $P\times_{Gl_n(\mathbb{K})} \mathbb{K}^n$ to some principal $Gl_n(\mathbb{K})$-bundle $P$, and any vector bundle connection on $E$ as one induced from a principal connection on $P$. In this case we have the principal $PGl_n(\mathbb{K})$-bundle $Q=P/\Delta$, where $\Delta$ denotes scalar multiples of the identity in $Gl_n(\mathbb{K})$, and the projective bundle associated to $E$ is $PE=Q\times_{PGl_n(\mathbb{K})} \mathbb{K}P^n\cong P\times_{Gl_n(\mathbb{K})} \mathbb{K}P^n$. It follows that any principal connection on $Q$ will induce a connection on $PE$.

I would suggest Michor's book "Topics in Differential Geometry" for some good reading that goes well beyond my very limited knowledge.

Comment: Thank you, that gives me some insight.  I agree that it seems a connection on a vector bundle will only descend to the projective bundle if it is equivariant with respect to the scalar multiplication.  Also, viewing the connection as induced from the principal bundle is probably a fruitful approach.  I am mostly looking for a useful way of expressing the right invariance of the connection on the principal bundle concisely for a connection on the projective bundle, which as you said I'm not sure is possible (I'm looking for a concise coordinate expression).

Comment: I like this answer but fail to understand one phrase in it. *Every* vector bundle connection respects scalar multiplication. In fact, this is a necessary and sufficient condition for a general connection on a vector bundle to be a vector bundle connection. So, I would say there is a bijection between connections on a vector bundle $E$ and projective (?) connections on the associated projective bundle.

Comment: It needs to respect the action of scalar multiplication with respect to the projection to the quotient space $E_0\rightarrow PE$, not just as a fibrewise map over $X$ (it is a principal $\mathbb{K}^*$-bundle). I'm not sure if this will necessarily be true for all vector bundle connections so I left the phrase in. The opposite direction is certainly not true, and in general there will be connections on the projective bundle that *do not* come from vector bundle connections. Consider the approach using principal bundles to see this easily.